# How do i go to next page of google with sllenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I made this little program but it's not working, basically what I want to do is, I want to scan all page 1 by 1 and if I get my desired website in the page I want to click on it,
but I'm stuck here on the next page

I tried with locating element by Link Text with this command
**Next_btn = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()** but nothing is working

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Navigate to the application home page
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# get the search textbox
search_field = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_field.clear()

# enter search keyword and submit
search_field.send_keys("Stranger things")
search_field.submit()

#goint to next page results
Next_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pnnext"]/span[2]')
Next_btn.click()
```

Comment: What do you mean _nothing is working_ ? What happens?

Comment: What you're error getting?

Comment: Using your code, it went to the 2nd page of search results.  What is not happening that you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure to use the WebDriverWait, so that the script will make sure the element is present before performing the operation.

Here is the tested code, which worked as expected.

**Imports required:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Code:**

```
url = "https://google.com"
driver.get(url)
# get the search textbox
search_field = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_field.clear()

# enter search keyword and submit
search_field.send_keys("Stranger things")
search_field.submit()

Next_Button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Next")))
Next_Button.click()
```

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the `check mark` on the left hand side in my answer.